# Tailwind: How to style element based on peer checked state, if target peer is descendant of sibling

Tags: tailwind-css

In the following example:

```html
<div>
  <input class="peer" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="peer-checked:text-red-600">
  <div>
     Nihilne te nocturnum praesidium Palati, nihil urbis vigiliae.
     Salutantibus vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Quam diu 
     etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Fabio vel iudice vincam, 
     sunt in culpa qui officia. Quam temere in vitiis, legem 
     sancimus haerentia. Quisque ut dolor gravida, placerat libero
     vel, euismod.
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/wCVr7xrBco

I am trying to change an element based of the checked state of the descendant of a sibling.

I've tried [arbitrary peers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#arbitrary-peers) but can't seem to create a custom selector that achieves this. I've also looked into [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) but I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around them and am not sure this is the right use case for them.

I wish I could just have the elements as direct siblings, but unfortunately in this situation that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `peer-has-[]` in Tailwind. It enables the class if a descendant of a peer has a certain state.

In your example, you can achieve the desired result like this:

```html
<div class="peer">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="peer-has-[:checked]:text-red-600">
  <div>
     Nihilne te nocturnum praesidium Palati, nihil urbis vigiliae.
     Salutantibus vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Quam diu 
     etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Fabio vel iudice vincam, 
     sunt in culpa qui officia. Quam temere in vitiis, legem 
     sancimus haerentia. Quisque ut dolor gravida, placerat libero
     vel, euismod.
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this functionality as noted by a comment, is available from Tailwind version 3.4 so make sure you're updated.
[See the Tailwind documentation link for this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-the-descendants-of-a-peer).

Comment: Thanks! This was in a recent Tailwind release: https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-4#new-has-variant - so make sure you're updated to at least 3.4 to be able to use this.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the div from around the input, it will work. Then the div with the text div is a direct peer from the input. Now, it is a peer of the div around the input.

```
<input class="peer" type="checkbox">

<div class="peer-checked:text-red-600">
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did say in the question "I wish I could just have the elements as direct siblings, but unfortunately in this situation that's not possible."